# Balance bike: fitting smaller wheels

Tags: wheels, bike-fit

I'm building a balance bike for a daycare kid. He is tall so I have a longer frame for him, but I think the tires might he too big. 
Can I put 12.5" tires on forks for 16" tires?

Comment: The main issue will be brakes (if you have any).

Comment: No brakes no chain just the feet.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming: 
- the axles are of a width that they will fit the dropouts and can be tightened down enough to prevent the wheels from falling off
- You don't have brakes or a drive train to consider (which you said you didn't in the comments)

...then why not? The bike will look a little funny, but the kid will dig it.